# Velocity stops in one direction but not in the other. unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been learning unity for a few weeks now, I have coding experience from before unity but there is 1 problem i'm stuck on right now that makes absolutely no sense to me at all.  basically I have a floor, and a player(capsule) and code that makes the camera follow the player and move the player.  My code is below but I have it set so it moves respectively with the arrows.  when I press left or right, it moves then stops.  If I press up or down, it never stops moving in that direction.  I narrowed it down to the Vector 3 values, the player will continue to move in the direction of the z value and not stop while the x value does not do the same thing.  The only way I could get the player to stop moving along the z axis was when I pressed another key(left,right,space) which would set the z value to 0. I would also appreciate it if someone would explain to me why the player slows down without me telling it to on the x axis.  My only guess of why this could be happening is because of something in the components of the player but I would have no clue what it would be.  Thanks for the help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{


    Rigidbody rb;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Start of camera movement
        float PlayerX = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x;
        float PlayerY = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.y;
        float PlayerZ = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.z;
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerX,PlayerY + 3.5f,PlayerZ - 6);
        //End of camera movement


        //Start of Player movement
        if (Input.GetKey("up")) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 5);
        }
        //Key Left
        if (Input.GetKey("left")) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(-5, 0, 0);
        }
        //Key Down
        if (Input.GetKey("down")) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, -5);
        }
        //Key Right
        if (Input.GetKey("right")) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        }
        //Key Space
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        }
        //End of Player movement



    }
}
```

I tried to figure out the source of the problem to try and solve it but I can't figure out how to solve it.  I was expecting the player to move in the correct direction while the key was held down and stop when it was lifted up.

Comment: I fixed my issue, I fixed it by freezing the rotation on all axis, this fixed 2 of my problems which was the velocity not stopping and player falling over.  I don't know how the rotation stopped the player from moving but it did so I don't need any help anymore unless someone wanted to explain this to me, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue, I fixed it by freezing the rotation on all axis, this fixed 2 of my problems which was the velocity not stopping and player falling over. I don't know how the rotation stopped the player from moving but it did so I don't need any help anymore unless someone wanted to explain this to me, but thanks!